# Blog structure like: blog.domain.com (on Shopify)

Tags: subdomain, blogs, tumblr, shopify

I am using Shopify to build an online store. I am wondering how some sites, e.g.:

http://www.ksubi.com

http://www.gamerprint.co.uk

are managing their blogs. Clearly, they have somehow integrated tumblr blogs so that they appear at blog.domain.com

This is something I am interested in doing, as I think the shopify option of domain.com/blog/blog etc is rather inelegant. I understand that my preference might not be optimal in terms of SEO, but I don't really care about that; I don't intend for the blog to draw users to my store.

With the above in mind, my questions are as follows:

1. How have these sites set up apparent subdomains on shopify? (I cannot access FTP, so I cannot do this) -- (BTW: I have purchased a domain from shopify, which I am using.)
2. How have they integrated tumblr to the blog.domain.com address?

Thanks for reading -- hope someone can help! :)

Comment: Messaging support@shopify.com or asking on the official Shopify Forums at http://ecommerce.shopify.com/ is your best bet here. Stack Overflow is a better match for programming questions.

Comment: ripsnorter: might I ask how you ended up asking on Stack Overflow? If there’s an official Shopify page directing you here, I’d like to change that.

Comment: Apologies if i posted inappropriately. I did post to the Shopify forums, but didn't get any responses. I wasn't directed here from Shopify. I just came directly. Thanks.

Comment: ripsnorter: ah, ok. Sorry about the lack of response on the forums :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Shopify Docs](http://wiki.shopify.com/Register_domain#What_if_I_need_to_change_my_domain_information.3F_.28WHOIS.2C_DNS_setup.2C_etc..29):

> ## What if I need to change my domain information? (WHOIS, DNS setup, etc.) #
>
> Shopify uses OpenSRS (Tucows) for domain registration and part
>   of the integration with Shopify is that you will be provided with a
>   web interface where you will be able to further configure your domain.
>   These details will be emailed to you upon registration of a domain.

So it sounds like there should be some information in that email that will direct you to a place to edit your domains registration information.  Then you can follow [Tumblr's instructions](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains) to set up the subdomain.

Comment: Thanks...I actually found the answer to my question, but as I am a new user here I had some problems answering my own question and marking it as solved.

Answer (score -1):

Okay...it seems like I had this back to front...

If anyone is interested, the solution is as follows:

The addresses such as "blog.domain.com" are actually Tumblr pages disquised as a shopify storefront. They are explained in the following examples:

http://www.webcrate.co.uk/tumblr/using-a-custom-domain-name-on-tumblr/

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

Of course, the Tumblr pages in question would need to include items like the header and nav from your shop (so as to look like part of your store) which you would have to add manually, and would unable to include your mini shopping cart in the header, or elsewhere, as this is Shopify's end.

If, as was the case with me, you have a domain from Shopify, you should use the emailed information (received when you registered the domain) to set up the subdomain on which the Tumblr blog will be hosted. i.e. the blog.domain.com subdomain. Then you can use the information above to point your Tumblr at this page.